# configuring network access via wifi dongle (adapter) FAILED

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-2, wireless-adapter, wicd-curses

I have a Wifi adapter for the Raspberry Pi that I want to use to get access to the Wifi network.

I have done all the steps from [this tutorial](http://www.raspyfi.com/wi-fi-on-raspberry-pi-a-simple-guide), using `Wicd-curses`, the wifi network was detected and I have selected a static ip and entered the following

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.3
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

and now, doing `ifconfig wlan0` shows me that my IP is `169.254.59.150` (it's different than `192.168.1.3`).

I was able to connect to the network correctly from the Raspbian Desktop but I can't connect to any page in the browser. And running:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 cannot fetch @adress No adress associated with hostname
```

when trying to connect via ssh:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.3 
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.3 port 22: No route to host  :arrow: 
ssh pi@169.254.59.150 
ssh: connect to host 169.254.59.150 port 22: Connection timed out
```

when trying with the ping command:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

all packets transmitted has been received 0% packet loss with:

```
ping 168.254.89.0
```

I get `Destination host unreachable` with:

```
ping 192.168.1.0
```

connect: network unreachable

```
    sudo ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ed:6c:fe  
          inet addr:10.42.0.12  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12960 (12.6 KiB)  TX bytes:12960 (12.6 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:8d:38:31:af:bf  
          inet addr:169.254.89.150  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9830 (9.5 KiB)
```

---

```
sudo iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"COMPANY"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:B9:68:E4:62:68   
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-0000-00   Security mode:open
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=62/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

---

```
  sudo route 
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

the file **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.42.0.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.42.0.0
broadcast 10.42.0.255
gateway 10.42.0.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Any help will be appreciated , thanks  :)

Comment: Could you cut&paste the output of sudo ifconfig, and sudo iwconfig, and sudo route,  and add that information to your question?

Comment: @joan please see the updated question , but what do you mean by sudo root it's output command not found

Comment: I meant sudo route (not root).  route gives the IP routing table.  It's probably irrlelevant.

Comment: You might one to replace any sensitive inormation with * (e.g. the encryption key).

Comment: Unplug the ethernet cable, reboot - then try again to configure the wifi.

Comment: @ifermon that's weird , the ethernet cable is unplugged  but i still get `inet addr:10.42.0.12` in eth0 , am i doing something wrong

Comment: Can you please add your /etc/network/interfaces file to your question.

Comment: @ifermon ok i have added it , please take a look

Comment: @joan i have added sudo roote , please take a look gyus :)

Comment: Thanks. That explains the eth0 addr. Since you're using wicd-curses try this guide instead: https://blog.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/easy-wireless-configuration-for-raspberry-pi/ -- make sure to back up your current interface file first before you make changes.

Comment: @ifermon i do have a backup , it's not necessary that i use wicd-curses but the most important is to resolve the problem with any method , i will try the new link ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to boot the Pi with the usb dongle attached.

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following to the bottom:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "your network name"
        wpa-psk "your password"
```

If you want to give it a static ip then just do:

```
    iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.XX          #static ip address
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.XX          #must match your router address
        wpa-ssid "your network name"
        wpa-psk "your password"
```

EDIT:
Without knowing your network type, etc., they most simple method is to use the GUI.

On fresh boot go to gui desktop using `startx`

Then open (should be on the desktop) `Wifi Config`

Hit `scan`

Connect to your network

EDIT 2:
Assuming WPA2 network:

Edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

And add

```
network={
    ssid="your network name"
    psk="your password"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but when rebooting i could not have an adress with ifconfig wlan0 and i get those 2 failure in boot up 'not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces failed'   and 'not running interfaces that will use a dhcp client'

Comment: Please see edit @Frankenstein